# SQL DATABASE datetime date query

Tags: python, sql, database

Getting error for below how to put date in variable for sql query?

```
for symbol in symbolist:
  datereplace1 = '2022-04-03 00:00:00'
  datereplace2 = '2022-04-03 00:00:00'
  query=(f"""DELETE FROM {symbol} WHERE  Time >=%s AND Time <%s""", )   #we can also delete older than x days by writing thisWHERE col <= date('now', '-10 day')
  cursor.execute(query, (datereplace1,datereplace2))
  test.commit()
```

cursor.execute(query, (datereplace1,datereplace2))
TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not tuple

Comment: Why do you have `{symbol}` in your f string but never define it?

Comment: hi thank you for your reply symbol is to loop from symbolist 
symbols = pd.read_sql("""SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type ='table'""",test).name
symbolist = (symbols.values.tolist())

Comment: Don't use an f string, just use a regular string, and it should work.

Comment: query=("""DELETE FROM {symbol} WHERE  Time >=%s AND Time <%s""", )     still getting same error :(

Comment: Use just `query=f"""..."""` without comma and parentheses.

Comment: without comman and parantheses    iam getting this sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error               query=f"""DELETE FROM {symbol} WHERE  Time >=%s AND Time <%s"""

Comment: Which database type (Sqlite, MySQL,...) are you using?

Comment: I am using Sqlite

Comment: Replace both `%s` by `?`. The notation of these placeholders varies between DB engines.

Comment: Yes, it Worked! Finally Thank you